# Exercises The sum of a range eloqent java

Tags: javascript, html

what does

```
step = start < end ? 1 : -1
```

in this function mean? it comes from the answers for the book called Eloquent Java, I don't know what question mark and colon sign in the context of function values mean

```js
function range(start, end, step = start < end ? 1 : -1) {
  let array = [];

  if (step > 0) {
    for (let i = start; i <= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  } else {
    for (let i = start; i >= end; i += step) array.push(i);
  }
  return array;
}

function sum(array) {
  let total = 0;
  for (let value of array) {
    total += value;
  }
  return total;
}

console.log(range(1, 10))
// → [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
console.log(range(5, 2, -1));
// → [5, 4, 3, 2]
console.log(sum(range(1, 10)));
// → 55
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called a ternary operation.

It's a single line equivalent of an if-else statement.

```
step = start < end ? 1 : -1
```

Is the same as saying

```
if(start < end)
    step = 1;
else
    step = -1;
```

---

The format looks like this

```
variable = (condition) ? true_value : false_value;
```

Comment: so why if step equals let's say -2, it won't be changed to -1 or 1 (since step can equal only to 1 or -1 ) in this program but the program will take -2 as the step

Comment: The whole operation is used for a parameter, which means it is a default value. The step will equal 1 or -1 if no step is provided based on the Boolean.